# Does `decltype` also perform evaluation of the expression?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, decltype

In this code, is `a + b` executed once or twice? What would be a good method to verify that?

```
double num3 = [](double a, double b)->decltype(a + b) { return a + b; }(1.2, 2.1);
```

Comment: once, it's in description of `decltype`. Albeit for a lambda that's not necessary in this case, their return value is defined by `return` statement.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you want to verify?

Comment: I wonder how many times a+b will execute

Comment: `decltype` doesn't evaluate its argument. It only needs to determine the type of the expression; for that, it's not necessary to actually evaluate said expression.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, the result of an expression inside a decltype declaration is not evaluated at runtime, but its type is evaluated at compile time.

So in the hypothetical statement:

```
double num3 = [](double a, double b)->decltype(a + b) { return a + b; }(1.2, 2.1);
```

the statement `a + b` is only evaluated once at runtime.

As explained in the comments, decltype() was not necessary at all in the above statement.  It is usually used to help the compiler in more complex cases, for example (in c++20):

```
// this would not compile without decltype()
auto special_add = [](auto a, auto b) -> decltype(a + b) { 
    if (a == 0) 
        return 0; // would default to int, but is explicitly declared as decltype(a + b) 
                  // in the declaration
    return a + b; 
};
```

As a general rule, avoiding unnecessary declarations helps keep code clutter down and makes the code more readable.  That's the reasoning behind many features new to c++11, 20 and 23.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across a similar question and decided to answer this question.

[[dcl.type.decltype] #1](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.decltype#1.sentence-2):

> The operand of the `decltype` specifier is an **unevaluated operand**.

And [[expr.context] #1](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.context#def:unevaluated_operand):

> [...] An unevaluated operand is not evaluated.

`a + b` in `decltype(a + b)` is not evaluated.